# stderr: <_io.BufferedReader name=8> when run the script with subprocess.popen()

Tags: python, popen

I am trying to run a script (myscript.py) using subprocess.Popen() function. The reason I want to use Popen() is that I want to run this script inside a thread and I want to be able to kill the process after stopping my thread. My code is as follow:

```
class my_thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, event): 
        super(my_thread, self).__init__()
        self._event = event

    def run(self):    
         command = ['python3', PosixPath('myrepo/myscript.py'), '-c', PosixPath('myrepo/config.json')]
          proc =  subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
          print(proc.pid)
          print(f'errr is: {proc.stderr}')
          print(f'stdout: {proc.stdout}')
...
def main():
    thread_event = threading.Event()
    mythread = my_thread(thread_event)
    mythread.start()
```

When I run the code I can see the process id (example below) but the stderr and stdout have the following output:

```
2604
errr is: <_io.BufferedReader name=8>
stdout: <_io.BufferedReader name=6>
```

I did some search for the error but could not find anything that help me. When I run this code using subrpocess.run() instead of subprocess.Popen() I have no problem and I can see all the printouts of my script running inside run() function while subprocess.popen() does not show me anything! I will be thankful for any comment to help me solve the problem.

Thanks.